# Is it possible in TSQL to have the first row be the column name?

Tags: t-sql

That would be extremely helpful when copying values from Sql Server Management Studio into Excel.

Is there such a template to pour my queries into?

Comment: From the grid? Use the "copy with headers" option. Or go "Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> Include column headers when copying or saving results"

Comment: @MartinSmith Why would you post that as a comment instead of an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing exists to make the first row contain the column headers, however as Martin Smith points out in the comments, if all you want to do is copy the results to Excel (or anything else) with the column headers included, you can right-click and use 'Copy with Headers'

[image]

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no option to make the column names part of the result set.

This is not surprising, since each column can only contain values of a single data-type - and it's quite unusual to have result sets where every column is text. So even if it was an option, it would be of limited utility.

Answer (score 0):

Dint quite understand your question, but you can export the data  Sql Server Management Studio to excel, Or select all rows right click copy and paste.